What is the `thon` executable?
On Ubuntu or other Linux-based systems, Python 3.14's venv creates an extra executable named thon:
$ python --version
Python 3.13.0
$ python -m venv .venv
$ cd .venv/bin && ls
Activate.ps1  activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  pip  pip3  pip3.13  python  python3  python3.13

$ python --version
Python 3.14.0a1+
$ python -m venv .venv
$ cd .venv/bin && ls
thon  Activate.ps1  activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  pip  pip3  pip3.14  python  python3  python3.14

What does it do and why is it there?

This is an easter egg. The thon executable works exactly the same as python, python3 and python3.14.
The name thon itself is a pun on "Python" and  ("Pi") the mathematical constant, whose decimal representation starts with "3.14".
This executable was originally named python as a parallelism to python3.14 and other python3.xx executables that are only created on non-Windows operating systems. python didn't make the cut, however, since people seem to like thon more.

"Remember, everyone: shhh!"

Well, this question has less than 100 views at the time of writing. There are way more Python programmers than that, so most of them will still be able to enjoy the surprise.

I wish I were one of them lucky ones who will get to enjoy the surprise.
